# Adding values to a list box from array WITH text

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm adding values from a file to an array and then adding those values to a list box in a form. I have methods performing calculations and everything is working great, but I'd like to be able to use a loop and insert the year prior to the values I am inserting into the list box. Is there a way to use the .Add method and include a variable which will be changing in this? Something like `populationListbox.Items.Add(i, value);` if `i` is my loop counter? Code is below so I'd like first line in the list box to have the year I specify with my counter, followed by the population. Like this, "1950 - 151868". As of now it only displays the value 151868. Thanks!

```
const int SIZE = 41;
int[] pops = new int[SIZE];
int index = 0;
int greatestChange;
int leastChange;
int greatestYear;
int leastYear;
double averageChange;
StreamReader inputFile;


inputFile = File.OpenText("USPopulation.txt");


while (!inputFile.EndOfStream && index < pops.Length)
{
    pops[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
    index++;
}

inputFile.Close();



foreach (int value in pops)
{
    **populationListbox.Items.Add(value);**
}

greatestChange = greatestIncrease(pops) * 1000;
leastChange = leastIncrease(pops) * 1000;
averageChange = averageIncrease(pops) * 1000;
greatestYear = greatestIncreaseyear(pops);
leastYear = leastIncreaseyear(pops);

greatestIncreaselabel.Text = greatestChange.ToString("N0");
leastIncreaselabel.Text = leastChange.ToString("N0");
averageChangelabel.Text = averageChange.ToString("N0");
greatestIncreaseyearlabel.Text = greatestYear.ToString();
leastIncreaseyearlabel.Text = leastYear.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
int i = 1950;

foreach (int value in pops)
{
   populationListbox.Items.Add(i.ToString() + " - " + value);
   i++;
}
```

Your life will be a lot easier if you stop trying to program C# as if it were 1980s C and use the power of it's Framework:

```
var pops = File.ReadLines("USPopulation.txt").Select(int.Parse);

populationListbox.Items.AddRange(pops.Select((p,i) => $"{i} - {p}"));
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Was having trouble with the syntax. Yeah this is an assignment so we have to put in what he's been teaching us. :) Thanks for the help!